# How to calculate daily sums from a dataframe (options chain data)

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate daily volume sums on a dataframe. The dataframe looks like this (it's an option chain):

```
     eod_date     expiry type strike  last   bid   ask volume
1 2015-05-11 2017-01-20 call   65.0  0.00  0.23  0.2      1
2 2015-05-11 2015-05-15 call   24.0  0.00 14.20 16.00     2 
3 2015-05-12 2015-05-15 call   27.5  0.00 13.95 15.65     4
4 2015-05-12 2015-05-15 call   30.0 11.90 11.45 12.05     9
```

The calculated output of daily volume sums should be a dataframe like this:

```
    eod_date  type volume
1 2015-05-11 call      3
2 2015-05-12 call     13
```

I have not been able to figure out a good way to do this. There are a lot of other metrics I'd like to calculate but figuring out this one would be the first step to implementing the others (like volume sums across different expiry dates). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(volume~eod_date+type, data=dat, FUN=sum)
#     eod_date type volume
# 1 2015-05-11 call      3
# 2 2015-05-12 call     13
```

Answer (score 2):

The `data.table` option would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(volume= sum(volume)) , list(eod_date, type)]
#     eod_date type volume
#1: 2015-05-11 call      3
#2: 2015-05-12 call     13
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(eod_date, type) %>% summarise(volume = sum(volume))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#Groups: eod_date
#
#    eod_date type volume
#1 2015-05-11 call      3
#2 2015-05-12 call     13
```